# JavaScript interval function in module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, intervals

I have a Little js "module" with an interval function which should Output a console log every second, but it just puts it out once what am I missing in this logic?

```
const calc = {

    render () {
        this.foo;
    },

    foo() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("test");
        }, 1000);
    },
}

calc.render();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: `this.foo()` ? Or `get foo() { }` ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want a function to be called repeatedly:

```js
const calc = {
  render() {
    this.foo();
  },

  foo() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("test");
    }, 1000);
  },
}

calc.render();
```